# ¿Por qué hay varios formatos al momento de declarar un componente?

Tags: reactjs

Al seguir los pasos de algunos tutoriales, en el archivo App.js tengo algo como lo siguiente:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Hola Mundo :) It is me learning React JS <code>src/App.js</code>.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sin embargo, este mismo archivo en los App.js de los tutoriales, aparece de la siguiente manera:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Hola Mundo :) It is me learning React JS <code>src/App.js</code>.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Me pregunto si me hace falta instalar algo o hice algo mal, ya que al reemplazar los bloques me produce un error. O no se, si tal vez se trate de alguna versión nueva de React.

Comment: Por lo que veo esta todo bien.
Sería mejor que nos muestres el error que te aparece y así poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia es que has declarado como función es un *"stateless" component* (componente sin estado) y el otro es un *"statefull" component* (componente con estado). [Esto no es nuevo ha existido ya desde hace tiempo en React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-function-components)

Como sabemos en React existen los props y los states, y hasta React 16.8 la única forma de utilizar el state en un componente era declararlo como una clase, de esta manera

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { counter } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {`Has dado click ${counter} ${counter === 1 ? 'vez' : 'veces'}`}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({counter: counter+1})}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Mientras que un "stateless component" no tendría *state*, **solo recibe props** por lo que haría imposible cambiar dinamicamente algún valor, **nótese como al ser una función, regresamos el JSX en lugar de ponerlo en una función `render()`**

```js
// Stateless component recibiendo props
function Stateless({name}) { // Recibimos el prop mediante "object destructuring"
  return(
    <h1>Hola {name}</h1>
  );
}

// Stateless component que no recibe props
function App() {
  return (
    <Stateless name="Carlos" />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

## ¡Hooks!

A partir de React 16.8 es posible utilizar el *state* y otras funcionalidades de React **sin declarar un componente como clase**, por lo que si utilizas esa versión no habría mucha diferencia en como funcionan, antes de React 16.8 **la unica forma de utilizar el state en un componente era declararlo como clase**

Un ejemplo de hooks:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      {`Has dado click ${counter} ${counter === 1 ? 'vez' : 'veces'}`}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter+1)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Conclusión:

> - Antes de React 16.8 la única forma de utilizar el state en un componente era declararlo como clase o utilizar una librería externa como [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) **(gracias [gugadev](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26302/gugadev))**
> - Una ventaja de usar un "functional component" (componente como función) es que al transpilarlo su nombre es minificado haciendo el bundle final más pequeño
> - El uso del `this` siempre ha sido complicado en JavaScript, utilizar clases lo hace más dificil, usar un "functional component" lo simplifica un poco ya que estamos trabajando sobre el *scope* de la función
> - La cantidad de código al utilizar un "functional component" es mucho menor, como se puede ver en el ejemplo

---

**Enlaces**

- [Componentes funcionales y de clase - documentación oficial de React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)
- [Hooks - documentación oficial de React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: Antes de hooks ya podías usar estados en SFC mediante [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose). Con la aparición de React Hooks, dicho paquete se descontinuó.

Comment: @gugadev he editado la respuesta para incluir lo mencionado. Gracias